# ode"ServerTimeout","message": "The request timed out. Diagnostic information: subscription id '', tracking id '**', request correlation id '*'."

Tags: azure-powershell

when i am trying to connect azaccount in powershell,i am getting this error while selecting subscriptions

connect-azconnect take longtime to connect with warning:Multiple error occured see details

Comment: `Multiple error occured see details` -- may me see the details please?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your command is correct:

1.connect to the Azure portal:

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

2.select your Subscription:

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "<SubscriptionId>"
```

You can use this command to get your subscriptions after you connect to Azure portal

```
Get-AzSubscription
```